# Как убрать отступы в iframe html для IE?

Tags: css3, html, internet-explorer, css

На странице имеется **iframe**, в который подгружается другая страница.
В IE появляется отступ справа для элемента **iframe html**.

Как его убрать?

Такая композиция селекторов не работает: `iframe html body { margin:0px; padding:0px}`

Comment: Если frameBorder="0" , проблема сохраняется?

Comment: Если у вас отступ у html, почему вы тогда обнуляете отступы у body, сделайте так:

    iframe html, iframe html body { margin:0px; padding:0px}